# PHP File upload with ajax based client side doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a form that uploads image to a certain path. I did not use this `<form action="file.php">` upon submission of form, instead I used ajax for the submission of form. The data are successfully saved in the database including the filename but the image wasn't uploaded at all. What is the problem with this? How could I fixed this one? Thanks for the help. Here are my codes:

form.php

```
 <form method="post" name="new_category" id="product_category" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
 <ul class="add_prod">
 <li>Category Title:<input type="text" name="category[title]" id="cat_title" value="" placeholder="Title" /> </li>
 <li>Category Description:<textarea rows="4" cols="40" name="category[description]"></textarea></li>
 <li>Category Image:<input type="file" name="image_file" id="cat_image" /></li>
 </ul>  
 </form>
```

file.js

```
$("#product_category").submit( function(){

    event.preventDefault();

   var data_category = $(this).serialize();
   var image = $("#cat_image").val();
   $.ajax({
       type: "post",
       url: "../wp-content/plugins/product_form/category_save.php",
       dataType: "json",
       data:data_category + "&image_file=" +image,
       success: function(data){
           if(data.notify == "Success"){
               console.log(data.notify);
           }
           else{
               console.log(data.notify);
           }
       } 

    });
 });
```

Save.php

```
<?php 
//establish connection
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","database"); 
//on connection failure, throw an error
if(!$con) {  
die('Could not connect: '.mysql_error()); 
} 

$folder = "../Dropbox/estacio/wp-content/plugins/product_form/img/";

if (is_uploaded_file($_POST['image_file']['tmp_name']))  {   
if (move_uploaded_file($_POST['image_file']['tmp_name'], $folder.$_POST['image_file']['name'])) {
     echo "File uploaded";
  } else {
     echo "File not moved to destination folder. Check permissions";
   }
  } else {
  echo "File is not uploaded.";
 } 



   //get the form elements and store them in variables
   $category_values = $_POST["category"]; 
   $image_url = basename($_POST["image_file"]);
   $image_field = "image_url";
   $data = array();

   //unset($view_all_info['Password2']);
   foreach($category_values as $field => $val){
    $data[] = "`".$field."` = '".$val."'";
   }

   array_push($data,"`".$image_field."` = '".$image_url."'");

   $sql = "INSERT INTO wp_product_category SET ".implode(',', $data);
   $ret = mysqli_query($con,$sql); 

   if($ret){
    $notification="Success";
   }
else{
  $notification="Failed";
   }

  echo json_encode(array('notify'=>$notification));

  mysqli_close($con);
 ?>
```

Comment: You need to use XHR2 which is only available in the most awesomest of browsers and the latest IE as well.

Comment: Your passing the filename in your ajax, but I'm pretty sure you will still need to access the file data stored in the `$_FILES` superglobal not `$_POST`.

Comment: Can you show me your code for this? Thank you for your help

Comment: Taking a look at the php functionality you are trying to use would be a good starting point. The [`is_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php) reference on php.net has a good example on it's use.

Comment: I tried to twist it but still files aren't uploaded. Is ther something to be changed in my ajax?Please help

Answer (score 0):

try checking $_FILES['image_file']['tmp_name'] or $_FILES['cat_file']['tmp_name'] instead of $_POST, post is only giving you the filename as passed by the argument, not the actual uploaded content.

also try adding action='category_save.php' to your form and using ajaxForm instead

```
$("#product_category").ajaxForm(
{
dataType:'json',
success:function(json){
   console.log('success');
}
}).submit();
```

using different id and name tags for your input forms isn't very wise either.